# Adding two different type of objects in array angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have two different arrays, heroes: Hero[] and monsters: Monster[]. They share a common field, named totalInitiative. These two arrays need to be put into the same array and sorted on their totalInitiative.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Array[hero1, hero2, hero3, monster1, monster2]
```

I created a superclass called Participant:

```
import {Participant} from './participant';

export class Hero extends Participant{
id: number;
name: string;
player: string;
hitPoints: number;
armor: number;
initModif: number;
imageUrl: string;
totalInitiave: number;
}

import {Participant} from './participant';

export class Monster extends Participant{
id:number;
name: string;
hitPoints: number;
armor: number;
initModif: number;
imageUrl: string;
}

export class Participant{

}
```

I did not add the common fields in Participant because I have a Hero and a Monster component where I need those common properties to  add a new Hero/Monster.

Now I need to adjust my Encounter model so it consists of a Participant[] which holds the Hero[] and Monster[]

```
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {Monster} from './monster';
import {Participant} from './participant';

export class Encounter {
id: number;
name: string;
participants: Participant[ Hero[] Monster[]]; //Doesn't work
}
```

I'm not even sure that this is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your array needs to be a union of `Hero` and `Monster`:

```
const participants: (Hero | Monster)[] = [];
```

Here is a cut down example with a rudimentary sort...

```
class Hero {
  constructor(public initiative: number) { };
}

class Monster {
  constructor(public initiative: number) { };
  evil = 5;
}

const heroes = [
  new Hero(5),
  new Hero(3)
];

const monsters = [
  new Monster(2),
  new Monster(7)
];

const participants: (Hero | Monster)[] = heroes.concat(monsters);

const sorted = participants.sort((a, b) => a.initiative - b.initiative);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thank you, edited my original post because I'm still missing something

Answer (score 1):

Both `Hero`s and `Monster`s are also `Participant`s, so you can simply say that `participants` is an array of `Participant` elements.

```
participants: Participant[] = [];
```

Comment: so I would still need my Participants super class?

Comment: Yes. This is obviously not the only solution, but it makes sense to use inheritance in this case.